# MySQL Where condition groupings from remote table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a products table referencing a products 'filter' table - this table contains such things as color, size, condition etc (attributes).

How do I go about building a query to show results from searches?

```
SELECT DISTINCT shop_products.*
FROM shop_products
JOIN shop_products_filters ON
 (shop_products.id = shop_products_filters.product_id)
WHERE category_id = '2' AND price >= '1.00' AND price <= '10.00' 
AND (filter_category_id = '161' AND filter_option_id IN (1046,1051))
AND (filter_category_id = '162' AND filter_option_id IN (1057,1058))
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Above is an example of my code that is not working.

Filter Category ID 161 = Color

Filter Category ID 162 = Size

Filter Option ID 1046 + 1051 are black,red etc

Filter Option ID 1057 + 1058 are small, medium etc

I know the SQL above won't work because filter_category_id cannot be both 161 and 162 - I'm pretty sure I'm missing a join of here somewhere - to check the filter options exist in the shop_products_filters table first.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: So, are you filtering products by several filter_category_id? E.g, you need products of this color and this size. Isn't it? . Which table holds filter_category_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EXISTS to check if that condition is met in another table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT shop_products.*
FROM shop_products
JOIN shop_products_filters ON
 (shop_products.id = shop_products_filters.product_id)
WHERE category_id = '2' AND price >= '1.00' AND price <= '10.00' 
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM shop_products_filters WHERE filter_category_id = '161' AND filter_option_id IN (1046,1051))
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM shop_products_filters WHERE filter_category_id = '162' AND filter_option_id IN (1057,1058))
ORDER BY price ASC
```